# Grails with GGTS (Eclipse): dbconsole not working or getting generated

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-plugin

Trying to teach myself groovy & grails using Eclipse GGTS and stumbling on what seems, according to all the documentation, a relatively simple thing. Accessing the dbconsole web based DB administration tool.

The documentation suggests that dbconsole is enabled by default in development mode, but even adding the settings (`grails.dbconsole.enabled = true` & `grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'`) to the various sections (development/test/production) in DataSource.groovy seems to have no effect.

Im browsing to the dbconsole locations like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/dbconsole` or `http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin/dbconsole`  and all conceivably rational URL variations on that, but it yields nothing, only 404s.

The rest of the howdy world app works, with some dynamic scaffolding UIs being generated and working just fine... but Im at a loss as to what I am missing on dbconsole.

Apologies for what is almost certainly a beginners mistake, any help or pointers would come in handy right about now.

Feel free to let me know if any more code or settings are worth adding into the question.

Thanks

Etc:

About Groovy/Grails Tool Suite

Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201310051614

DataSource.groovy, dev:

```
development {
 dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"


            //grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
            //grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
        }
}
```

Comment: Those settings go in Config.groovy, not DataSource.groovy

Comment: Thanks Burt. Adding it into Config.groovy instead sorted it.

Comment: Cool, I converted the comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Those settings go in Config.groovy, not DataSource.groovy